# TypeORM - Create user with relations

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

When a new user signs up, I want to create a number of relations to be automatically be set up as well. Currently, I am doing it this way:

```
const user = await User.create({
  email,
  password: hashedPassword,
}).save();

const settings = await Settings.create({
  userId: user.id,
}).save();

const settings = await Profile.create({
  userId: user.id,
}).save();
```

From what I've read, transactions are the best way to handle dependant operations, but PG doesn't create user ID until it is saved.

This is the best I could come up with transactions:

```
const user = await User.create({
  email,
  password: hashedPassword,
}).save();

const settings = await Settings.create({
  userId: user.id,
});

const profile = await Profile.create({
  userId: user.id,
});

await getConnection().transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
  await transactionalEntityManager.save(settings);
  await transactionalEntityManager.save(profile);
});
```

However, there is still the possibility that the user saves, but the relations do not.

Is there a better (or easier way) to handle this?

**user.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email!: string;

  @Column()
  password!: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Settings, (settings) => settings.user)
  settings: Settings;

  @OneToOne(() => Profile, (profile) => profile.user)
  profile: Profile;
}
```

**settings.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Settings {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: number;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.settings)
  user: User;
}
```

**profile.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Profile {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: number;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.profile)
  user: User;
}
```

Comment: Please share the entities code

Comment: Added entities code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save` method loads the relations before `INSERT`, therefore it is not possible to perform `save` for `settings`, The generated query will first try to `SELECT` the `user` and only then `INSERT` `settings`, as you said - inside a transaction it is not possible to select uncommitted records, and that why it doesn't work.

What can be done? Two options:

1. Save the entities nested

```
const user = await getConnection()
.transaction((transactionalEntityManager) => {
   const userObj = User.create({
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
   })

   userObj.profile = Profile.create({});
   userObj.settings = Settings.create({});

   return transactionalEntityManager.save(User, userObj);
});
```

2. Insert the user, and then insert the `settings` and `profile`

```
const userInsertResult = await getConnection()
.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {

const userInsertResult = await transactionalEntityManager
                .createQueryBuilder(User,'user')
                .insert()
                .into(User)
                .values({
                   email,
                   password: hashedPassword
                }).execute();

const settingsInsertResult = await transactionalEntityManager
                .createQueryBuilder(Settings,'settings')
                .insert()
                .into(Settings)
                .values({
                   userId: userInsertResult.raw.id
                }).execute();

const profileInsertResult = await transactionalEntityManager
                .createQueryBuilder(Profile,'profile')
                .insert()
                .into(Profile)
                .values({
                   userId: userInsertResult.raw.id
                }).execute();

 return userInsertResult
});
```

Comment: Option 1 didn't work, but Option 2 did. Now, let's say I had a field called profileId in User. I can only create a profile after creating a user, but I can't add profileId to the user until I create the profile. How do I then take id from profileInsertResult and add it to userInsertResult?

Comment: I made a mistake ob option 1, fixed the example now, this should work and answer your question.
The issue is that the `create` method doesn't do deep creation. but save does.

Comment: I think I might misunderstand in the first read. When you have this kind of relationship, only one side will be the owner of it, only one side will have a reference to the other, you either have `projectId` on `user` or `userId` on `project`. First create the one that will be referenced later, then create the other one with the reference identifier.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, Noam. Unfortunately, Option 1 still doesn't work.